# Do male marsupials have a pouch?

Tags: zoology, marsupials

Do male marsupials have a pouch, or is it a female organ only (like the womb)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most marsupials, only the females have a pouch. However, males of the [water opossum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_opossum) and the extinct [tasmanian tiger (or thylacine)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thylacine) also have a pouch.  The males of both the thylacine and water opposum used/use their pouch to keep their genitalia from getting entangled in vegetation.

Comment: ...evolution can even make underwear!

Comment: Not all male thylacines had it, but yes, some did.